# How can I find the most studied SNP of a gene?

Tags: bioinformatics, database, gene, snp

How can I find the most studied SNP of a gene and diseases that the most studied SNP has been related to?

I search in dbSNP database but I can't find it.

What is the process?

Comment: I have selected the BRCA1 gene.

Answer (score 1):

Can you provide the gene of interest?

You can usually search Entrez for the gene symbol in the dbSNP database, which will pull up a NCBI Entrez page for SNPs located in the gene and will also give an indication of their clinical significance (benign or otherwise).

Alternatively, if you have a specific disease in mind, you can check more specific databases for a SNP, such as [COSMIC](http://cancer.sanger.ac.uk/cosmic) for cancer-related SNPs.

Lastly, merely Googling the gene of interest (for example, "EZH2 SNP") in Google Scholar will bring up articles that present SNPs of interest.

Some combination of those methods should yield what you want, but I might be able to provide a better answer with more info.